# Function onclick event listener that uses the id of the clicked button within the function

Tags: javascript, function, this, addeventlistener

I am currently working on a rock paper scissors code which is seeking to add 1. event listeners for the buttons
2. use the selected button as the playerSelection when running the game() function 
3. Alert the outcome

I have not started working on the score iterations ++ portion however I cannot get the outcomes to alert. I researched and found out about this id and used some of the tutorials I was pointed to in order to select all buttons but I am running into blocks. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    </head>
     <body>
      <div id="container">
    <button id="rock">Rock</button>
    <button id="paper">Paper</button>
    <button id="scissors">Scissors</button>
    </div>

    <script>


    let pScore = 0
    let cScore = 0
    let ties = 0

     // buttons is a node list. It looks and acts much like an array.
     const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

     // we use the .forEach method to iterate through each button
     buttons.forEach((button) => {

     // and for each one we add a 'click' listener
     button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

      function game() {
      let playerSelection = this.id;
      let computerSelection = computerPlay();
      return playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);

        function computerPlay() {
          let cChoices = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
          let cThrow = Math.floor(Math.random()* 3);
          return cChoices[cThrow].toLowerCase();;
        }

        function playRound() {
        alert("Player picked " + playerSelection);
        alert("Computer selected " + computerSelection)
        if (playerSelection === computerSelection) {
          alert("Tie game, move on to the next round and play again");
          ties++
      } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection == "paper"){
              alert("You lose...what a wimp");
              cScore++;

      } else if (playerSelection == "rock" && computerSelection ==        
              "scissors"){
              alert("You win, outstanding job!");
              pScore++;

      } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == "rock"){
              alert("You win, outstanding job!");
              pScore++;

      } else if (playerSelection == "paper" && computerSelection == 
      "scissors"){
              alert("You lose...what a wimp");
              cScore++;

      } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == 
       "paper"){
              alert("You win, outstanding job!");
              pScore++;

      } else if (playerSelection == "scissors" && computerSelection == 
        "rock"){
              alert("You lose...what a wimp");

      } else {
        alert("something has gone terribly wrong");
      }
      alert("Player score is " + pScore, "Computer score is " + cScore, "Ties 
      = " + ties)

       }
      }
      });
     });

     </script>
       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using an arrow function in `button.addEventListener()`.  Arrow functions get `this` from the scope where they were created, so it doesn't contain the element that you clicked on.

You can use `event.target` or `button` in place of `this`, e.g.

```
let playerSelection = button.id;
```

or

```
let playerSelection = event.target.id;
```

Or you can change the arrow function to a traditional function:

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    ...
});
```

Another suggestion: rather than passing the ID around, just pass the element itself. This saves you from having to call `document.getElementById()` all over the place when you want to do something with the element.

Comment: Barmar, 

    Thanks for responding. I have a followup for you (in the learning stages so my apologies if it takes a second for it to sink into my brain) 

"The problem is that you're using an arrow function for the event listener."

is it the for.each.button arrow function or the event listener arrow function...

event.target and button : would that be used as player selection or in place of the arrow function(and with or without parenthesis) 

and the change to a traditional function : I would replace the arrows with function()?

all that said...is the remaining code clear?

Comment: It's the arrow function in `button.addEventListener`. I've updated the answer to clarify the rest.

Comment: Thanks so much Barmar. This paired with some more research and I made it functional!